# Correlation Expression with WSO2 ESB Aggregate Mediator

Tags: wso2-esb

I have two responses as below:

Response 1:

```
{

    "hotelSet":[
        {
            "hotelname":"hotel1",
            "hotelcode":"A-1000",
            "id":"1000"
        },
        {
            "hotelname":"hotel2",
            "hotelcode":"A-1002",
            "id":"1001"
        }
    ]

}
```

Response 2:

```
{

    "hotelSet":[
        {
            "hotelname":"hotel1",
            "hotelcode":"B-1000",
            "id":"1000"
        },
        {
            "hotelname":"hotel2",
            "hotelcode":"B-1005",
            "id":"1005"
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to aggregate these both responses into a response by checking the `id` is same.

Aggregated response:

```
{

    "hotelSets":[
        {
            "id":"1000",
            "hotels":[
                {
                    "hotelname":"hotel1",
                    "hotelcode":"A-1000",
                    "set":"A"
                },
                {
                    "hotelname":"hotel1",
                    "hotelcode":"B-1000",
                    "set":"B"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"1001",
            "hotels":[
                {
                    "hotelname":"hotel2",
                    "hotelcode":"A-1002",
                    "set":"A"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":"1005",
            "hotels":[
                {
                    "hotelname":"hotel2",
                    "hotelcode":"B-1005",
                    "set":"B"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]

}
```

How can I check both response's `hotelSet/id`? How to use the correlation expression in this case? Or else is there any other way?